# Loop through Datatable based on criteria set by user

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, datatable

I am relatively new to posting on here but have been stuck on this loop for quite sometime. In the commented section of the code I have successfully written a for loop that does what it is intended to. I have even gone as far as to make sure that I was successfully getting the filtered row count and number of groups from the textbox that the users fills in. However, I need a loop that iterates through the filtered datatable and assigns each row to a group that is set by the user and only if supported based on row count divided by the min number that a team can hold and not exceeding the max number that can be on a team. Finally the results with the added column showing what group the row is in needs to populate another datagridview in this case datagridview2. All of this takes place on a button click. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks....

```
 private void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        const double maxTeam = 16.00;
        const double minTeam = 6.00;
        double peopleCnt = 0.00;
        int numGroups = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumGroups.Text);
        int j = 1;
        double totPeopleCnt = Convert.ToDouble(fdt.Rows.Count);

        //MessageBox.Show(totPeopleCnt.ToString()+"&"+numGroups.ToString());

        //fdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RandomNumber", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));

        //        for (int i = 0; i < fdt.Rows.Count; i++)
        //        {
        //            fdt.Rows[i]["RandomNumber"] = rnd.Next();
        //        }

        //        DataView fdv = new DataView(fdt);
        //        fdv.Sort = "RandomNumber";
        //        dataGridView2.DataSource = fdv.ToTable();


        //fdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RandomNumber", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));

        if (totPeopleCnt / minTeam < Convert.ToDouble(numGroups) || totPeopleCnt / maxTeam > Convert.ToDouble(numGroups))
            if (totPeopleCnt / minTeam < Convert.ToDouble(numGroups))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Number of Players entered will not meet team minimums for " + txtNumGroups.Text + " Teams.");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totPeopleCnt; i++)
                {
                    peopleCnt++;
                    fdt.Rows[i][j] = rnd.Next();
                    j = (j == numGroups ? 1 : j + 1);
                }


                DataView fdv = new DataView(fdt);
                fdv.Sort = numGroups.ToString();
                dataGridView2.DataSource = fdv.ToTable();
            }
    }
```